# download Amazon S3 file using SSIS script task

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, ssis, script-task

I'm trying to connect to Amazon S3 bucket using SSIS script task and because i'm not an expert at all in C# coding in SSIS, could anyone please help me achieve this and below i have a sample example from the internet of a C# code of how to download a csv file from amazon s3 bucket but i need to write it according to SSIS C# standards.

https://vimalshekar.github.io/codesamples%20scriptsamples/Downloading-from-S3-bucket-In-CSharp

Note: i have downloaded the awssdk.s3 plug in so i have done the pre requisites

Comment: Response1 is a stream.  So use following :            byte[] data = new byte[response1.Length];
            response1.Read(data, 0, (int)response1.Length);
            File.WriteAllBytes("filename",data);

Comment: In this example, all the steps are explained quite clearly. You send the name of a zip file to the web service and it downloads and extracts the file with the address you provided.

Comment: @meysamasadi can we connect on email to discuss it further ? it is not exactly what i want from that website it is a little different. - my email is vanimalge@gmail.com

Comment: First problem you're going to run into is that while you can use a nuget package during development of a Script Task/Component, when the editor session closes, that nuget package is discarded. During execution, there is no step where the package will attempt to re-acquire the assembly.

Comment: Oh i did not think about this and that is why whenever i closed SSIS package and reopened it i had to always download amazon sdk @billinkc

Comment: If the assemblies are signed, you can add them to global assembly cache (GAC) but that will need to be done per computer the package is executed on. People have asked questions about using local, non-GAC'ed, assemblies with SSIS but I've never gotten around to trying the different approaches I've seen used.